# How can I build a follow system in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I switch from Firebase realtime database to Firestore
In the realtime database, I was using this code for the follow system:

```
checkFollowingStatus(user.getUID(), holder.followButton)
holder.followButton.setOnClickListener {
            if(holder.followButton.text.toString() == "Follow")
            {
                firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                            .child("Follow").child(it1.toString())
                            .child("Following").child(user.getUID())
                            .setValue(true).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                    firebaseUser?.uid.let { it ->
                                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                                                .child("Follow").child(user.getUID())
                                                .child("Followers").child(it.toString())
                                                .setValue(true).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful) {

                                                    }
                                                }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                            .child("Follow").child(it1.toString())
                            .child("Following").child(user.getUID())
                            .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                    firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
                                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                                                .child("Follow").child(user.getUID())
                                                .child("Followers").child(it1.toString())
                                                .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful) {

                                                    }
                                                }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                }
            } }
       private fun checkFollowingStatus(uid: String, followButton: Button) {
    val followingRef = firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Follow").child(it1.toString())
                .child("Following")
    }

    followingRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(datasnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (datasnapshot.child(uid).exists()) {
                followButton.text = "Unfollow"
            } else {
                followButton.text = "Follow"
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })

}
```

It looks in realtime database Like this
+Follow
   +userId
     +Following
        +usersId...
     +Followers
        +usersId...
How Can I convert this to Firestore or How can I structure a follow system in Firestore database?

Comment: You can structure it in similar fashion but after the userId node in both Followers and Following you will have to add some fields related to that userId. Means Follow = collection, userId = Document, Following or Followers = Collection, userId = Document and finally fields related to that perticular UID

Comment: Yes I try it but there's an error in the line where there's .set(true).addOnCompleteListener(I convert setValue(true) to set(true) I don't know if this is correct)...  this is the error: "Data must be a Map<String, Object> or a suitable POJO object, but it was of type: java.lang.Boolean setvalue"

Comment: In firebase database your leaf node looks something like this, key : value, what you error is telling you is you have to put leaf node there that is key : value pair in your set method. Create a hashmap and put key and value in the hashmap and pass the hashmap to the set method

Comment: I'm still a beginner can you explain it in  kotlin code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var hashMap : HashMap<String, Object> 
           = HashMap<String, Object> () 

hashMap.put("someName", true);
```

and pass this hash map to set method

```
databaseRefernce.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot or QuerySnapshot>() {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
      if (value.exists())  {
      }
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! but when clicking the follow button it gets saved in firestore but the button doesn't get changed to unfollow. the addValueEventListener isn't working. what should I use instead?

Comment: In OnStart method you can listen for changes in the database for that specific mode and change the button accordingly

Comment: In the firebase realtime database I was using AddValueEventListener to listen for changes but I don't know what is the alternative of this in firestore. I try addSnapshotListener but I face issues in the "if(datasnapshot.child(uid).exists())" I can't get the right code for firestore @50_Seconds_Of_Coding

Comment: You should be diving more into documentation rather than just asking on stack overflow I updated my answer please  check it out